# How to store public/private key in MS SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, public-key, private-key

Within my code I generate public/private key pairs. I would like to store them to a MSSQL2008 database table. My current table has a column for public key and one for private key, both of which are of type varchar.

Is there a way for me to store the keys as they are, or do/should I convert them to String and store them as varchar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the idea of storing unencrypted private keys in unsecured storage is questionable, you could use [`binary` or `varbinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) data type to store the bytes of your keys without converting them to `varchar`.

Comment: +1 for the notion that storing keys unencrypted in a unsecured storage area being questionable.

Comment: I also find it questionable but unfortunately that's the requirements given to me for my proof-of-concept =]